# How do I make a table in bootstrap which has a title and 4 cells per row?

Tags: css, laravel

I am trying to create a table which has a centered title (which is essentially one row) and then has multiple columns spaced out evenly as table elements in the body. However when I try this, the table title field spazzes out and gets sized down which I don't want.

What I want is essentially this:

[image]

However when I try to do what I had in mind: this happens.

[image]

My code that I (tried to) use to create the table as in the desired example:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid">
    <table class="table">
       <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="lopendeopdrachten">Opdrachten</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>test<td>
                <td>test<td>
                <td>test<td>
                <td>test<td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>  
</div>
@endsection
```

I am programming this in laravel which includes bootstrap for reference.

If anything is still unclear please do ask. Also, if this is a duplicate question I apologize. I couldn't find any comparable problems, though.

Comment: try `<th class="lopendeopdrachten" colspan="4">Opdrachten</th>`

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the `colspan` attr

```
<th class="lopendeopdrachten text-center" colspan="4">Opdrachten</th>
```

Comment: Your question was partly correct. I had to double the span from 4 to 8 for the full row to return for some odd reason. Now to see if I can have the cells equally spaced out..

Comment: Could you paste the full HTML code or a Screen shot URL of the dsired result , so we can help ?

Comment: I already figured it out. In my case I had to double the colspan with the amount of cells I needed.

For example: If I had a row with 4 cells, I'd have to make the table header span 8 to get the desired result.

Comment: Well, glad if my answer helped !

Answer (score 0):

what you want is a table with an irregular header right? [This link](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/irregular/) should have all your needs for irregular tables like irregular rows and headers. It's not really a bootstrap problem but an HTML one so I think referring to the link given above should give what you need.